# Synology NAS/cloud solution over port 80

Tags: nas

I would like to store my files and music on a personal cloud and access it/ stream it from anywhere.
(and occasionnally manage a torrent client )
I would like to be able to access it on a local network as well via a windows/linux file explorer.

But the real problem is for web based part: it should be on port 80: I currently own a synology nas, but it uses ports 5000, 4000, etc to access it's functionnalitiy, and my company firewall prevent me from accessing the music and files app.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Port forward 80 externally to 4000/5000 or whatever your WebGUI of the NAS is on through your router. See http://portforward.com/routers.htm for guides based on your router make/model.

Comment: But I can't forward port 80 to every single port the services are suing, can't I ?